# submit event occure before ajax response

Tags: ajax

In my Site I have used below code. but ajax work only If we add alert.

```
$(document).submit(
        function(){

            if(document.getElementById('time_i').innerHTML != '')
            {
                var flag = false;
                var str = document.getElementById("time_i").innerHTML;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                  {  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  }
                else
                  {
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                  {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {

                    }
                  }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","URL"+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();

                }
        });
```

Please provide me solution.

Comment: I can't tell what your question is.

Comment: You obviously don't understand the `asynchronous` part of AJAX.

Comment: I just want to store value in database using ajax. on submit event but submit event occur before AJAX Call Response... but if i add alert on response then its will store in database, so means we need to add delay ,so we will get value in database..

Comment: yes I don't understand asynchronous part of AJAX.. as i am new in AJAX..

Answer (score 1):

You should add `event` to the arguments list of the function declaration at the top, and then write `event.preventDefault();` inside the if-statement. This will prevent the form from changing the page on you.

If you're wanting to change the page anyways, then you likely shouldn't be using Ajax in the first place, but a regular old form submission.

The 'asynchronous' aspect of 'AJAX' is that the call doesn't block. It will return immediately, and then upon completion it will perform a callback on a function if you gave it one.

Comment: Above Code won't work for me, because user is not redirect to next page. like on next question page.

Comment: If you want the user to automatically be redirected, you need create a callback function for your Ajax, which will be called upon completion of the Ajax request, which can send the browser to the next page. Of course, if that's all you do, then you're really just using the wrong tool, and the right tool would be to ditch the JavaScript (Ajax), and just submit the form using plain HTML.